# Does every Hamiltonian equation can be written in a some system of coordinates as a canonical Hamiltonian system

Tags: dynamical-systems, mathematical-physics, symplectic-geometry, hamilton-equations, integrable-systems

Does every Hamiltonian equation can be written in a some system of coordinates as a canonical Hamiltonian system i.e. $\exists(q,p)$ such that
$$\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}\dfrac{dq}{dt}=\partial_p \mathcal H\\[0.3cm]
\dfrac{dp}{dt}=-\partial_q \mathcal H\end{cases} 
\end{equation*}$$

And if yes, this is always the case even if the solution of the equation belongs to an infinite dimension space ?

Comment: On [standard definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_system#Overview) a system is Hamiltonian when its equations of motion are written in this form. What's your definition?

Comment: @Conifold I think they are referring to the dynamics generated by the Hamiltonian vector field $X_{\mathcal{H}}$, the vector field satisfying $\iota_{X_H} \omega=dH$.

Comment: This is true locally in finite dimensions as a consequence of [Darboux's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem)

Comment: Yes, J.V.Gaiter  is right, I mean equation of the form $\partial_t u=X_{\mathcal{H}}(u)$

Comment: And so globally, it will depend on the equation if we have a global coordinate system...